# Copy and Paste from excel to windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, keycode

I have made use of the `_KeyDown` function in my windows form:

```
if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.V) && (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

and then have used to get the copied data:

```
 string[] clipboardRows = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText).Split(new string[] {"\r\n"},
                                                                                                 StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This works fine, however when you select say selected cells from a spreadsheet it ends up copying all cells in between for example:

```
1.Test
2.Test2
3.Test3
4.Test4
```

If i select both `test` and `test 4` using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and then copying by pressing <kbd>C</kbd>, when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and stepping through it gets all in between so `test2` and `test3`.

How do i resolve this?

Comment: how do you resolve "what"? what do you expect a paste to do in such scenarios?

Comment: This is not a WinForms or C# issue. That's just how Excel copy + paste works. Multiple discrete selections only work within Excel. Try pasting the same selection even in Word and you will find that the clipboard actually contains all cells in between.

Comment: jmh_grm, I was not aware of this... slightly dissapointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you why you cant do it. I recorded a Macro in Excel, entered four rows of data. I selected cell A1 and A4, press Ctrl + C

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "abc"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "def"
Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "hij"
Range("A4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "klm"
Range("A4,A1").Select    'It actually concatenates the cells you've selected, that info isn't in the clipboard, if I selected three cells in the column it would be Range("A4,A1,A2").Select
Range("A1").Activate
Selection.Copy  

'Range("B1").Select
'ActiveSheet.Paste   'when I paste onto new cells, only two rows are taken up
```

You can do this in VSTO eg [Copy & Paste VSTO - Excel Power Tools](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/1f671283-1187-43d2-a3fd-a4f8c7ae4efc), but thats another question.